# VBA Loop Through Cells if matches certain criteria but something in another cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, logic

I am creating an OUTLOOK.HOL file based on information provided in a Excel spreadsheet.

[image]

Column D contains the following:

**IF HEADER**
=CONCATENATE("[_Firm Holidays ",LEFT(B1,FIND(" ", B1)-1)," - ",F3, "] ", "3") <--"3" is the row count for a particular country, manually handled as I couldn't figure out how to do a count between two rows. Although these are all "3" this is a sample some have more

**IF HOLIDAY**
=IF(G4="Choice of Employee","",CONCATENATE(TRIM(B4),IF(E3="Dubai")," (Estimate)", ""),",", TEXT(C4,"yyyy/m/d")))

Column E contains the following:

=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(B3,"firm's ")," Office")

Column F contains the following:

=IF(E3="U.S.","US")

Column G contains the following:

=C4

The following values need to change depending on which row its on:

CONCATENATE("[_Firm Holidays ",LEFT(B1,FIND(" ", B1)-1)," - ",F3, "] ", "3") ***F3***

IF(G4="Choice of Employee","",CONCATENATE(TRIM(B4),IF(E3="Dubai")," (Estimate)", ""),",", TEXT(C4,"yyyy/m/d"))) ***G4/B4/E3***

TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(B3,"firm's ")," Office") ***B3***

IF(E3="U.S.","US") ***E3***

=C4 ***C4***

Is this possible to automate in Excel? I assume I would loop around all column B rows and have an if statement or something like:

If contains "the firm" then xyz
if contains "religious holidays or empty" do nothing
else handle the holiday

Comment: I cannot understand what you try doing... What do you want automating? Exporting the Excel sheet you show to OUTLOOK.HOL? Do you want a macro to automatically write formulas you show? At the question "Is this possible to automate in Excel?" the answer is **Probably, yes**. But what to be automated? If you already have the necessary formulas, why to automate? If you want creating a HOL file extracting data from Excel, you should show us how this file looks. I only know that outlook uses it for keeping the holidays. I do not know how the respective file keeps the necessary data and you must show

Comment: Do you only like asking questions, no offence?